# Vuex store data always reside in memory?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

First of all, I would appreciate your understanding of my poor English.
I wonder if Vuex's store data always resides in memory.

Let me explain with an example.
When entering page A, we received a list from the server and implemented it to be stored on the store.
Does this mean that when I enter page A and move to page B, the list of A will remain in memory even though it is not used?

Doesn't this cause memory overflow in very large applications?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The entire page state (including the DOM and Javascript/Vuex data) will remain in memory provided that a full page reload did not occur (which would be the case if you're using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/)). This is called a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (SPA).

In a SPA, you need to ensure that you drop any references (e.g. set to `null`) to large objects and arrays when they are no longer needed so that the memory can be freed by the garbage collector.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I don't know why this has no upvotes. This is a extremely simple and useful point.

Comment: My question was this, why didn't they choose local storage ?