# What does "in memory" means in the context of web applications?

Tags: web, memory, browser

I read a lot about how a state manager X stores data in memory, or how React renders my component tree in memory. I know that "in memory" is somewhat temporarily, meaning is not persistent like a database. But what exactly "in memory" IS in the context of web browsers? How browsers are able to transfer the data from state manager or React components to this memory?

Links for articles, papers and blog posts are also appreciated =))

Edit for including examples using this terminology:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html - right in the first paragraph it states that "UI is kept in memory"

[Vuex store data always reside in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940662/vuex-store-data-always-reside-in-memory) - another example of the terminology "in memory"

Comment: Please provide links to examples of the use of the terminology "in memory" in the context of web browsers that you don't understand.  (It is hard to explain what someone else means it you can't see that they said.)

Comment: sure, I'll edit my question @StephenC =)) thanks for the input!

Comment: All computer programs run "in memory."  In both of your examples the phrase is redundant.   "In Memory" is equivalent to "in the DOM" or "in javascript" in the contest of web browsers.  There are some local storage features in browsers, but the application still holds its runtime state "in memory".